# How to simulate the secure services in IEEE 1609.2 in VANET using VEINS and OMNet++?

Tags: cryptography, simulation, omnet++, adhoc, veins

I've been trying to learn about the **VANET** simulating framework **OMNet++** and simulator **VEINS**.

I'd like to apply the crypto operations in **IEEE 1609.2** like **ECQV-ECDSA** or **ECDH** into the **VANET** scenario.

**VEINS** and **OMNET++** are chosen to help me do that.

**Question:**

How can I use them and some **C++** crypto libraries to explicitly simulate the process (e.g. the certificate data transmission from **RSU** to **EV**)?

Comment: I think this is much too broad at the moment. You should focus on a particular problem.

Comment: Hi, @jww What I really want to learn about right now is whether VEINS provides a certain module or function to implement those security services in IEEE 1609.2. I read the tutorial and source code but not helping. Take ECQV implicit certificate for example, does VEINS really not implement this scheme or just I missed something? If I want to simulate the ECQV process in VANET, do I have to write my own code using Openssl or other libraries in OMNET++ rather than learning and using the function in VEINS? Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: What you are asking for is currently not implemented in Veins, so would need to be implemented. Note, however, that for most simulations it is not necessary to actually encrypt the data in order to model the effects of such encryption (introducing latency, increasing message sizes). See, for example, https://doi.org/10.1109/ACCESS.2017.2717999